# R code for eye tracking data (fixations, saccades) collected by a mangold eyetracker

Tags: r, eye-tracking

I have collected eye data in an experiment, where readers read a short text.
My data is organized so that one row represents one tracking point (usually every 8ms). The sampling rate of my eyetracker is 60Hz.
Below, I provide an example of the data:

```
  No. Name Time..ms. Timegap..ms. Duration Gaze.X Gaze.Y Pupil.Diameter.Left..mm.
1   1  P 1         0            0        0    692    515                     2,87
2   2  P 1         8            8        8    679    474                     2,87
3   3  P 1        16            8        8    698    479                     2,89
4   4  P 1        24            8        8    704    499                     2,86
5   5  P 1        33            8        8    706    435                     2,86
6   6  P 1        41            8        8    692    429                     2,84
  Pupil.Diameter.Right..mm. X.offset Y.offset Mouse.X.coord Mouse.Y.coord
1                      3,06        0        0          5133          2679
2                      3,02        0        0          5133          2679
3                      3,02        0        0          5133          2679
4                      3,02        0        0          5133          2679
5                      2,95        0        0          5133          2679
6                      2,95        0        0          5133          2679
                             AOI Left.Eye.X Left.Eye.Y Right.Eye.X Right.Eye.Y Blinks
1 AOI_4.0.1,AOI_4.1.3,AOI_4.2.28        731        332         654         701     NA
2 AOI_4.0.1,AOI_4.1.3,AOI_4.2.28        715        260         645         687     NA
3 AOI_4.0.1,AOI_4.1.3,AOI_4.2.28        740        302         656         659     NA
4 AOI_4.0.1,AOI_4.1.3,AOI_4.2.28        729        316         679         682     NA
5 AOI_4.0.1,AOI_4.1.3,AOI_4.2.28        762        277         651         596     NA
6 AOI_4.0.1,AOI_4.1.3,AOI_4.2.28        748        252         640         607     NA
  Detection trial_column AOI_4_0_1 AOI_4_1_3 AOI_4_2_28 AOI_4_1_4 AOI_4_2_43 AOI_4_1_2
1        NA           NA      TRUE      TRUE       TRUE     FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
2        NA           NA      TRUE      TRUE       TRUE     FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
3        NA           NA      TRUE      TRUE       TRUE     FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
4        NA           NA      TRUE      TRUE       TRUE     FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
5        NA           NA      TRUE      TRUE       TRUE     FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
6        NA           NA      TRUE      TRUE       TRUE     FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
```

In the AOI Columns, there is the information wether the eyes hit the aoi at this time point or not (single AOIs represent the single words). I struggle with finding the right R package for this (most eyetracking packages are designed for specific eyetrackers) or do not take looking into AOIs in consideration. I would be happy for any recommendations on this.

I tried to write a code myself where a definition of a minimum of 13 rows in a line represents a fixation, but I struggle with getting out the fixation duration.